# How is DataAreaId field related to FiscalCalendarPeriod table in Dynamics AX 2012?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I tried many approaches but none of them seems to get me a concrete relation between FiscalCalenderPeriod table and the DataAreaId attribute in dynamics AX 2012.

DataAreaID was a part of LedgerPeriod in Dymanics AX 2009, but now this table has been depriciated, so the data has been normalised.

How can I map FiscalCalenderPeriod with a Company Data i.e. dataareaid?

Answer (score 3):

A `DataAreaId` identifies a Legal entity (a record in the `CompanyInfo` table). Each Legal entity has a Ledger (a record in the `Ledger` table where the `PrimaryForLegalEntity` field is the `RecId` of the `CompanyInfo` record). A Ledger is tied to a `FiscalCalendar` record by the `FiscalCalendar` field. `FiscalCalendarPeriod` records also belong to a particular `FiscalCalendar` based on the `FiscalCalendar` field.

There is a helper class `FiscalCalendars` that has many methods for dealing with Fiscal calendars. For example, here's one way to get the end date of the current period for the company 'CEU':

```
RecId fiscalCalendarRecId=Ledger::fiscalCalendar(CompanyInfo::find('CEU').RecId);
date currentDate=SystemDateGet();
date endDate=FiscalCalendars::findPeriodEndDateByDate(fiscalCalendarRecId,currentDate);
info(date2StrUsr(endDate));
```